# The easiest way to move an object to 3D cursor

Tags: objects, 3d-view, 3d-cursor

What's the easiest way to move an object to the 3D cursor? The easiest way I know of is copying and pasting the coordinates in the right menu of the viewport. Is there an easier way to do it?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Select the object and then bring up the Snap-To menu with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and then choose “Selection to cursor”.

---

As mentioned by @JoanCharmant, Blender version 2.8+ allows you to right-click in the viewport to get a context menu that provides an easy way to get to the 'Snap' options instead of requiring the use of a keyboard shortcut. This option wasn't present at the time this answer was originally written.

Comment: Also in the main right-click context menu > Snap > Selection to cursor. For those that don't want to remember yet another keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Good point @JoanCharmant - although when the answer was written, this was Blender versions prior to 2.79 and it was 'rightclick-select' rather than a context menu. It's very strange going back to the other user interface - I very much prefer the 2.8+ version now.